# problem with images and css on prerender in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, prerender

I already know that I should use a middleware, but I would like to know how.

I have this source:

```
const prerender = require('prerender');
var server = prerender({
chromeFlags: ['--no-sandbox', '--headless', '--disable-gpu', '-- 
remote-debugging-port=9222', '--hide-scrollbars', '--disable-setuid- 
sandbox']
});
server.start();
```

When I go on: http://51.255.193.x:1337/render?url=https://www.google.com/ I don't see it because the files: css and images, they  are required directly as: http://51.255.193.x:1337/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png, and this link obtain 400 error (bad request)

How can I fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Generally prerender will not look for css and images. we will use Prerender mainly  for SEO, for SEO purpose title, meta tags and description kind of information is required.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because visiting this URL in your browser:

`http://51.255.193.x:1337/render?url=https://www.google.com/`

Will then cause the browser to load any relative links in the resulting HTML from the domain of `http://51.255.193.x:1337/`

So like you said, using a middleware so that the HTML is served through your website will fix any issues with relative links.